# Migrating from JobScheduler to WorkManager seems like a massive undertaking. Any advice+

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I've used `JobScheduler` for a while now. A typical example would be:

`JobScheduler` triggers the `onStartJob()` method. This kicks off some sort of task that might include several other background processes (getting device position, making a network call, etc). I then use an interface to call back to the `JobService` once the task is complete or if it fails.

However, with `WorkManager` it seems like there is basically no way to run work asynchronously. I know `WorkManager` will run Workers in a separate thread but it seems like a single worker must run synchronously? If so I'll have to rework a lot of the logic in my app it seems unless I'm missing something.

Say I had a weather app and it would use the `JobScheduler` to run a `JobService` that did the following:

`onStartJob()` --> get device position --> make API request for local weather data -> write to database -> call jobFinished()

With `WorkManager`, is the intended implementation of something like this to chain multiple workers together? And if so, how do you pass data from one Worker to another? Again, seems like it would be a massive undertaking for any slightly complex app to migrate to the `WorkManager` API.

Comment: There's [documentation on chaining work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) plus a [whole set of documentation pages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading) about threading in WorkManager, including how to [handle callback-based asynchronous work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a `ListenableWorker`. It has exactly that interface. Rather than you having to call `jobFinished()` in the end, we do the work for you when you resolve the `ListenableFuture`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#startWork() is analogous to `onStartJob` in your case.